# Jackson should not ignore root element tag in multi root xml content

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have the following xml content which I want to deserialize to JSON,

**Input Content**

```
<TransmissionAck>
    <EchoedTransmissionHeader>
        <TransmissionHeader>
            <ReferenceTransmissionNo>26218</ReferenceTransmissionNo>
        </TransmissionHeader>
    </EchoedTransmissionHeader>
</TransmissionAck>
```

**Expected output**

```
{
  "TransmissionAck": {
     "EchoedTransmissionHeader":{
        "TransmissionHeader":{
          "ReferenceTransmissionNo":"26177"
         }
      }
  }
}
```

**Actual Output**

```
 {
  "EchoedTransmissionHeader":{
    "EchoedTransmissionHeader":{
        "TransmissionHeader":{
           "ReferenceTransmissionNo":"26177"
         }
  }}}
```

I am passing dynamic content from RestController(Spring Boot)

```
Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> otmXmlResponse = webRequestsService
                .handlePost(Files.readString(Paths.get(outputFile.getAbsolutePath()), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
String body = otmXmlResponse.block().getBody();
String r = testXmlResponse(body);

============

public <T> T testXmlResponse(String xml) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        xmlMapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule().addDeserializer(JsonNode.class,
                new JsonNodeDeserializer() {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5947022035338738709L;

                    public JsonNode deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
                            throws IOException {
                        XMLStreamReader xmlP = ((FromXmlParser) p).getStaxReader();
                        String rootName = xmlP.getLocalName().toString();
                        return ctxt.getNodeFactory().objectNode().set(rootName, super.deserialize(p, ctxt));
                    }
                }));

        JsonNode entries = xmlMapper.readTree(inputFile);
        String json = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(entries);
        return (T) json;
}
```

When I run a unit test I get expected output, but when I call the deserialize method as above with dynamic content from controller, the sub-root element is taken as root. I cannot use a POJO for mapping. Any idea how I can get the expected output using Jackson library? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I used

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.json</groupId>
   <artifactId>json</artifactId>
   <version>20140107</version>
 </dependency>

import org.json.*;

public class ConvertXML {
public static String xml = "<TransmissionAck>\r\n" + "    <EchoedTransmissionHeader>\r\n"
        + "        <TransmissionHeader>\r\n"
        + "            <ReferenceTransmissionNo>26218</ReferenceTransmissionNo>\r\n"
        + "        </TransmissionHeader>\r\n" + "    </EchoedTransmissionHeader>\r\n" + "</TransmissionAck>";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        JSONObject json = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
        String jsonString = json.toString(4);
        System.out.println(jsonString);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

 }
}
```